# newcommand: cannot include macro as argument

Tags: macros

I feel a bit stupid, but I why can't I put macros inside the argument of my `newcommand`? And why can't my macro `\pra` work inside the `align` environment, while it definitely works if I just write manually the expanded macro?

My macro (to denote probabilities):

```
\newcommand*{\pr}[2][]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\Pr[\,#2\,]}{\Pr_{#1}[\,#2\,]}}
```

That is supposed to produce something like that:

[image]

This works:

```
\pr[b \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
```

This fails:

```
\pr[\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
```

with the error:

```
ERROR: Use of \\pr doesn't match its definition.

--- TeX said ---
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...l.18 ...k{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
                                                  \]
```

And still stranger, inside an `align` equation, the version `\pr` of the macro that used to work now fails, while if I write everything manually it works...

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand*{\pr}[2][]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\Pr[\,#2\,]}{\Pr_{#1}[\,#2\,]}}

\newcommand*{\pra}[2][]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\Pr[\,#2\,]}{\Pr_{\substack{#1}}[\,#2\,]}}

\begin{document}
This works:
\[\pr{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]
\[\pr[b \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]
\[\Pr_{\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}}} [a = 0 \mid b = 0]\]
This fails:
% \[\pr[\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]
% \[\pr[\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]

But if I put substack inside, it works:
\[\pra[a \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]
\[\pra[a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]

Now, it's still stranger: if I put the full expression without my macro, it works inside an align:
\begin{align}
  \Pr_{\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}}}[a = 0 \mid b = 0]
\end{align}
But if I use the macro that was used before, it fails:

% \begin{align}
%   \pra[a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
% \end{align}

% even if I use protect:
%\begin{align}
%  \pr[\protect\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
%\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In general you can give macros as arguments, you just need to be a bit careful what you do with those arguments. Not all macros can deal with all inputs. `\ifthenelse` doesn't seem to be too happy with complex beasts like `\substack` (I think `\ifthenelse`'s `\equal` tries to expand the strings it compares, which goes wrong because `\substack` is not expandable). I would replace `\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}` with `etoolbox`'s `\ifblank{#1}`, which does no expansion here.

Comment: Whoa amazing, I don't even need to protect with `\ifblank`, and it also solves the issues in `align` environment! Thanks! Feel free to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can give macros as arguments, but you may need to be a bit careful what you do with those arguments. Not all macros can deal with all inputs equally well.

`\ifthenelse` doesn't seem to be too happy with complex beasts like `\substack`. I think `\ifthenelse`'s `\equal` test tries to expand the strings it compares, which goes wrong because `\substack` is not expandable. In that case a healthy does of `\protect` before unexpandable content may help, but that probably gets tedious after a while.

I would replace `\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}` with `etoolbox`'s `\ifblank{#1}`, which does no expansion and thus needs no additional help to deal with even complex stuff like `\substack` here.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\pr}[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {\Pr[\,#2\,]}
    {\Pr_{#1}[\,#2\,]}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \pr[\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\protect\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

The fact that `\ifblank` does not expand its argument while `\equal` does means that there are differences in the behaviour of the two tests.

Compare

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand*{\imblank}{}

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\imblank}{}}
  {T}
  {F}

\ifblank{\imblank}
  {T}
  {F}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\ifthenelse` test is a bit fragile. There are much better ways to cope with empty optional arguments.

With `xparse` the test for a nonappearing optional argument is possible with the argument type `o`. See the “easy definition”, that I comment out because an even better one is possible, using `\pr*` instead of a different command to insert `\substack` when needed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

%%% Easy version
%\NewDocumentCommand{\pr}{om}{%
%  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
%   {% no optional argument
%    \Pr[\,#2\,]%
%   }
%   {% optional argument is expressed
%    \Pr_{#1}[\,#2\,]%
%   }%
%}
%%% Better version
\NewDocumentCommand{\pr}{som}{%
  % * = use substack
  % #2 = optional
  % #3 = mandatory
  \Pr\IfValueT{#2}{_{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\substack{#2}}{#2}}}[\,#3\,]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\pr{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
\\
\pr[b \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
\\
\pr*[a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

What happens? If the optional argument doesn't appear, `\IfNoValueTF` returns the true branch, otherwise the false branch. This is reversed with `\IfValueTF`. Here we can abbreviate to `\IfValueT`, because we don't need to do anything when the optional argument is missing.

Inside this conditional text we use another conditional: if `*` is present after `\pr`, `\IfBooleanTF` returns the true branch and the optional argument is surrounded by `\substack`. Otherwise the plain argument is used.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to avoid using `NewDocumentCommand` because I add some bad experience where `NewDocumentCommand` needed a pretty recent version of xparse to handle correctly facultative arguments, and that version was not yet pushed on overleaf, but maybe the issues does not apply here. Thanks!

Comment: @tobiasBora The used features have been stable for a few years.

Comment: Ok thanks. I can't remember which option was the bad one (maybe it was in fact the `+b` in `NewDocumentEnvironment`?). I can't accept two answers, but I really like your answer as well, thanks!

Comment: @tobiasBora Nowadays Overleaf uses TeX Live 2019, IIRC, so that should be no longer a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Need to `\protect` the `\substack` in an optional argument [when `\ifthenelse` is being used].

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand*{\pr}[2][]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\Pr[\,#2\,]}{\Pr_{#1}[\,#2\,]}}

\newcommand*{\pra}[2][]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\Pr[\,#2\,]}{\Pr_{\substack{#1}}[\,#2\,]}}

\begin{document}
This works:
\[\pr{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]
\[\pr[b \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]
\[\Pr_{\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}}} [a = 0 \mid b = 0]\]
This [no longer] fails with \verb|\protect|:
 \[\pr[\protect\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]
 \[\pr[\protect\substack{a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]

But if I put substack inside, it works:
\[\pra[a \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]
\[\pra[a \leftarrow \{0,1\}\\b \leftarrow \{0,1\}]{a = 0 \mid b = 0}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have two questions: 1) first, a minor question: can I make sure I don't need to protect my substack? 2) more interesting, do you have a solution for the second part of my question, where even protecting inside `align` statement fails? (sorry I added the second part while you was writting the answer, if needed I can create another question)

Comment: Actually, as noted in the comments, using`ifblank` from `etoolbox` has two advantages: I don't need to `\protect`, and everything works in `align` environment!

Comment: @tobiasBora It looks like you have your answer then...reformulate the check to not use `\ifthenelse`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, and thanks for your help, I'll keep my thumb up!